# << Operator Overloading for object causes error when accessing attributes inside overloaded method

Tags: c++

There is a line(cout << e.src) in the overloaded method for << that causes error. Removing that line causes the error.
The error doesn't show any stacktrace.
It just prints

> Segmentation Fault(core dumped)

```
#include <queue>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class Edge{
    public:
        int src, dest;
        int flow=0;
        int capacity;
        Edge* residual;

    Edge(int src, int dest, int capacity){
        this->src = src;
        this->dest = dest;
        this->capacity = capacity;
    }

    void augment(int bottleneck){
        int previousCapacity = this->getRemainingCapacity();
        cout<<"augmenting edge ("<<src<<"->"<<dest<<")chaging flow from "<<this->flow<<" to ";
        this->flow+=bottleneck;
        this->residual->flow-=bottleneck;       
        cout<<this->flow<<" and capacity from "<<previousCapacity<< " to "<<this->getRemainingCapacity()<<endl;

    }

    bool isResidual(){
        if (capacity==0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    int getRemainingCapacity(){
        return capacity - flow;
    }


    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Edge& e){
        out<<e.src; //THIS LINE CAUSES AN ERROR, FUNCTION WORKS PERFECT IF THIS LINE IS COMMENTED

        // Edge* ed = &e;
        // out<<e.src;
        // out<<"Edge("<<e.src<<"->"<<e.dest<<")| flow="<<e.flow<<"| capacity="<<e.capacity<<" | residual capacity = "<<e.getRemainingCapacity()<<endl;
        return out;
    }


};

class NetworkFlowSolverBase{
    public:
        int V;
        int source;
        int sink;
        vector<Edge*>* adj;

    NetworkFlowSolverBase(int source, int sink, int V){
        this->V = V;
        this->source = source;
        this->sink = sink;
        adj = new vector<Edge*>[V];
    }

    void addEdge(int source, int dest, int capacity){
        Edge* e1 = new Edge(source, dest, capacity);
        Edge* e2 = new Edge(dest, source, 0);

        e1->residual = e2;
        e2->residual = e1;

        adj[e1->src].push_back(e1);
        adj[e2->src].push_back(e2);
    }

    virtual void solve()=0;
};


class FordFulkersonBFSSolver: public NetworkFlowSolverBase{

    public:

    void bfs(int source,int sink, bool visited[], int parent){
        queue<pair<int, Edge*>> currentEdgeParentEdge;
        currentEdgeParentEdge.push({source, NULL});
        while(!currentEdgeParentEdge.empty()){
            pair<int, Edge*> top = currentEdgeParentEdge.front();
            cout<<*(top.second)<<endl;
            visited[top.first] = true;
            currentEdgeParentEdge.pop();
            for(vector<Edge*>::iterator it=adj[top.first].begin();it!=adj[top.first].end();it++){
                if (!visited[(*it)->dest]){
                    currentEdgeParentEdge.push({(*it)->dest, (*it)});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void solve(){
        cout<<"ford"<<endl;
        bool visited[V]={false};
        bfs(source, sink, visited, -1);

    }

    FordFulkersonBFSSolver(int source, int sink, int V): NetworkFlowSolverBase(source, sink, V){

    }

};


int main()
{

    int n = 6;
    int s = 0;
    int t = n-1;

    FordFulkersonBFSSolver solver(s, t, n);

    //edges from source
    solver.addEdge(s, 1, 16);
    solver.addEdge(s, 2, 13);

    solver.addEdge(1, 2, 10);
    solver.addEdge(2, 1, 4);
    solver.addEdge(1, 3, 12);
    solver.addEdge(2, 4, 14);
    solver.addEdge(3, 2, 9);
    solver.addEdge(4, 3, 7);

    //edges to sink
    solver.addEdge(3, t, 20);
    solver.addEdge(4, t, 4);
    solver.solve();

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are the errors? Please include them in the question

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question.

Comment: the actual error is probably somewhere else. Segfault can be caused by invalid pointers and the like. The question would be better if you removed as much as possible from the code (while making sure it still reproduces the error). Also read about [mcve]

Comment: I cannot find where you call the `operator<<` :/

Comment: cout<<*(top.second)<<endl; this causes to enter << method

Comment: yes just found it. I would bet on `top.second` being an invalid pointer

Comment: Please read about [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). For example that header does not exsit on my system so I cannot help you debug it.

Comment: @churill I edited it to use queue and iostream only

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 so how should I solve this invalid pointer and how you reached to this conclusion?

Comment: coming to this conclusion is simple: As a rule of thumb for every raw owning pointer there is at least one bug in the program, ergo you have a bug in your code ;). Fix is to use smart pointers or at least check if the pointer is valid before using it

Comment: Thanks, A lot @formerlyknownas_463035818, found the issue. Actually the very first pointer is NULL. Actually when I tried just printing top.second, instead of *(top.second), I realized the first element is NULL and rest are valid pointers pointing to some address.